# Is a loop an ear?

Tags: graph-theory

Is a loop an ear?

Take the graph with a single vertex and a loop connecting to itself.  Is this graph an ear decomposition of itself?

Comment: Sorry I should add... it looks to me like it is but I want to be sure.

Comment: It looks like it to me too, but I can't tell without knowing what your concrete definition of "ear" is (or "graph", as it might disallow such loops altogether).

Comment: Please provide definitions of the terms you are using.

Comment: @Arthur I used the definitions in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition